# back button at root controller of uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController application with a root view controller and each time I am pushing a view controller to the stack. Let's say the stack is A B C D where A is the root view controller here. The issue is that when I am at view controller D and do a popToRootViewController it went back to A but A has a back button on it. When I click on back the back just slides in and disappear, why is this happening?

**EDIT:** I am actually subclassing my UINavigationController so that I can set my rootViewController as follows:

```
#import "CustomNavigationController.h"

@implementation CustomNavigationController

@synthesize fakeRootViewController;

//override to remove fake root controller
-(NSArray *)viewControllers {
    NSArray *viewControllers = [super viewControllers];     
if (viewControllers != nil && viewControllers.count > 0) {  
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:viewControllers];        
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0];  
    return array;   } 
    return viewControllers; }

//override so it pops to the perceived root
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    //we use index 0 because we overrided “viewControllers”
    ((UIViewController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    return [self popToViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:animated]; }

//this is the new method that lets you set the perceived root, the previous one will be popped (released)
-(void)setRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController {
    rootViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [self popToViewController:fakeRootViewController animated:NO];
    [self pushViewController:rootViewController animated:NO]; }

- (void)dealloc {
    self.fakeRootViewController = nil;
    [super dealloc]; }


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        UIViewController *fakeController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.fakeRootViewController = fakeController;
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[super viewControllers]];
        [array insertObject:fakeController atIndex:0];
        self.viewControllers = array;
    }
    return self; }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use. }

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/* // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView { }
*/

/* // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; }
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil; }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); }

@end
```

**MORE UPDATE:**

So after I set my rootViewController and then push a viewController and then tried to call popToRootViewController from that view, it all worked fine. However, if I push another viewController after the second one and then call the popToRootViewController, now I can see that weird back button on the root.

Comment: Is it possible you're pushing A on the stack (again) before you push the other views on the stack?

Comment: If you try popping to root, getting rid of the extra back button, going back into the stack, and popping to root again, is the back button still there?  If it's not, that would imply you're pushing A onto the stack upon initialization.

Comment: As a sanity check, you could enumerate the UINavigationController viewControllers property and verify which controllers have been added to the stack.  This would settle the question of whether an additional instance of A has been pushed onto the stack.  Does the back button title give a clue as to which controller it is?

Comment: sorry.. I missed the very important part of this, I actually subclassed my own UINavigationController such that I can set the root view controller as above..

Answer (score 0):

I too face the same problem. So in your root controller assign leftBarButtonItem equal to nil.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

If your root controller reusing in the program. Then you need to check ->

```
BOOL needBackBarButton = (1 < [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]) ? YES : NO ; 
if (! needBackBarButton)
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

For other controllers

```
if (needBackBarButton)
{
          // Create custom navigationItem here.
}
else 
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Comment: but then how do I make a back button for those that I need?

Comment: You no need to think about other controllers. You just add self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil; this in your Root Viewcontroller's viewDidLoad method. I hope this should resolve your problem.

Comment: I did have that and it didn't change a thing